# VMWare serial ports

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, vmware-server, vmware-workstation, serial

Can someone tell me the difference between the different ways **virtual serial ports** can be configured using VMWare Infrastructure?

For instance:

- What is the difference between "use output file"  and "use named pipe"?
- Can "Use Output File" be used to connect 2 machines?
- When using a "named pipe", can that just be an arbitrary fifo on the shared SAN?  Does it need to be created in advance, or will vmware create it as needed?
- When using a "named pipe", I assume one server needs to be configured as "server" and the other as "client", and that it doesn't matter which one is which - is that correct?
- What does "Yield on CPU poll" mean - and which mode is better for a constant serial port connection?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A Named pipe virtual serial port behaves more like a traditional
  serial port - with both input and output, while an 'Output file' is
  mostly useful for quickly capturing  program output to a file.
- An "Output file" would not be useful 
  for bidirectional       communication
  between machines.
- The actual name of the named pipe is declared in the setup for the virtual machine.
- The selection of which named pipe is the server and client does not matter; a client can only connect to a server.
- "Yield on CPU poll" applies to special applications which communicate with the serial port by polling.   Kernel debuggers are an example; when blocked while debugging an interrupt, no further interrupts can be reliably processed.  This setting would not apply to typical inter-machine connections over named pipe serial ports.